# Why is Taylor Series an exact match of the original function instead of an infinitely close approximation?

Tags: taylor-expansion

If we must write the $f(x)$ in the form of a [general power series](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lec37.pdf), then I know all the following steps to calculate the coefficients.

However, how do we know that $f(x)$ can be written in such a form without losing any accuracy? There was once a linear approximation, then quadratic approximation. All of them are merely approximation. Why the series becomes the exact match when we raise the order of $n$ to $+\infty$?

Is there a convergence proof? By the way, I am also new to the "radius of convergence" concept. Probably they are related.

Comment: The proof for convergence of most Taylor series is related to the analysis of the remainder after $n$ terms. Are you aware of Lagrange or Cauchy form of remainder in Taylor's theorem?

Comment: First of all, the phrase "infinitely close" doesn't make mathematical sense: if a mathematical expression (even one defined by a limit or infinite series) equals another expression, they're actually equal, not infinitely close to each other. As for your main question, look at [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117714/prove-taylor-series-converges-to-f) for the general idea of how one can prove that a Taylor series converges to (that is, equals) the original function. It's not automatically true, but it holds for most of our familiar functions.

Comment: The Taylor theorem itself does not guarantee convergence, it only gives a remainder after $n$ terms. The convergence depends on the function involved as well as the point about which Taylor series is written. Most analysis books deal with a few examples where they show convergence (or divergence) for specific functions by analyzing remainder.

Comment: There are functions where the Taylor series does not converge to $f.$ The famous example is: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x=0\\e^{-1/x^2}&x\neq 0\end{cases}$$ This function has Taylor series at $x=0$ with all coefficients zero. Functions $f$ whose Taylor series converge to $f$ in some non-trivial region are called “analytic.”

Comment: Of course, some functions don’t have a full Taylor series at all, if the function isn’t infinitely differentiable at $x_0.$

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1):

If a function has a power series representation around $x_0:$
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(x-x_0)^n$$
for all $x\in (x_0-r,x_0+r)$ for some $r>0,$ then $f^{(n)}(x_0)$ exists for all $n$ and $$a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}.$$

If $f$ is a function defined on some interval $(a,b)$  such that $f(x)$ has a power series representation around every $x_0\in (a,b),$ then $f$ is called **analytic** on $(a,b).$

Note, Taylor series of analytic functions don’t necessarily converge for all $x.$ The function $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$ is analytic on $(-\infty,\infty),$ but the maximum radius $r$ for any $x_0\in(-\infty,\infty)$ is $r=\sqrt{1+x_0^2}.$

Analytic functions are important in calculus and real analysis, but they are the heart of complex analysis. In complex analysis, analytic functions are the core of the topic.

Some properties of analytic functions:

1. Polynomials are analytic.
2. If $f,g$ are analytic on $(a,b),$ then $f+g, f\cdot g$ are analytic on $(a,b).$
3. If $g(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ then $\frac fg$ is analytic.
4. (Composition) If $f$ is analytic on $(a,b)$ and $g$ is analytic on $(c,d)$ with $(c,d)\subseteq f((a,b))$ then $h(x)=g(f(x))$ is analytic on $(a,b).$
5. (Inverse functions) If $f(x)$ is analytic on $(a,b)$ and $x_0\in (a,b)$ with $f’(x_0)\neq 0,$ and $y=f(x_0)$ then there is an analytic function $g$ on some interval $(c,d)$ containing $y$ such that $g(f(x))=x.$
6. If $f$ is analytic on $(a,b)$ then $f’$ exists and is analytic on $(a,b).$ Also, any anti-derivative of $f,$ $F’=f,$ on $(a,b)$ is analytic there.

The most important analytic function which doesn’t follow from the above is $f(x)=e^x.$ A lot of the most basic analytic functions, like $\log$ and the trigonometric functions, follow from $e^x$ and the above rules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean exactly by "infinitely close approximation", but an "infinitely close approxmation" sounds like an exact match. Example from a simpler domain: $0.9999...$ (infinitely many $9$s) is $1$, not an approximation to $1$.

There are cases when there is no convergence, ie step-functions. The error does not go to $0$. You can find more about it if you look into [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon). As an illustration, here is an image [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon#/media/File:Gibbs_phenomenon_250.svg):

[image]

The error doesn't go away even if you send $N$ to infinity.

Comment: Gibbs is related to Fourier series not Taylor series.

Comment: Yeah, any function which is not infinitely differentiable at $x_0$ doesn’t have an infinite Taylor series at $x=x_0,$ , much less a converging one. And at the points $x_0$ of continuity, the step function has a (trivial) converging Taylor series in an interval which converges to the function.

Comment: If I understand correctly, we only use the verb "converge" for infinite series. For finite series, we use "equal" directly. Now the question has two parts: 1st, if the function is infinitely differentiable, does the infinitely long Taylor series converge to $f$ for given $x$? 2nd, if not infinitely differentiable, is the finite series we got equal to $f(x)$? I guess the 2nd is trivially true, but no proof in mind.